# Solving $d = \frac{v^2}{2g} \left( 1+ \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{2g y_0}{v^2 \sin^2{\theta}} } \right)\sin{2\theta}$ for $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, projectile-motion

> $$d = \frac{v^2}{2g} \left( 1+ \sqrt{  1+ \frac{2g y_0}{v^2 \sin^2{\theta}}  } \right)\sin{2\theta}$$

Need to find an equation for the angle.

This is the equation for the range of a projectile thrown from a height at an angle. I have tried to solve it myself and even used sites like Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab but to no avail. Could anybody please help?

[The equation and derivation for the range of projectile launched at an angle from a height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile)

Comment: Look up formulas for sin and cos in terms of tan of half angle. This will lead you to polynomial equation.

Comment: There is a simpler equation

Comment: Where? I want the equation for a projectile launched at a height.

Comment: The solution will be very big!

Comment: Yeah, I need this for game project I am doing. That's why this is so hard!

Comment: @ShamimAkhtar after you mentioned that there's a simpler result, I tried deriving it and got the exact result given by the OP. Could you mention the result that you're referring to?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider I have another doubt regarding this question. If theta is zero, then wouldn't the distance essentially become zero? Does that make this equation false?

Comment: I found the answer here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile

Comment: @PseudoApocaleone1 I'm pretty sure it won't be zero... theta is measured from the horizontal right?

Comment: @ExtremeRaider, yes. Theta is measured from the horizontal. So, if the object is thrown at zero degrees, shouldn't there still be distance based on velocity? Sin2x, will basically make the whole equation zero, don't you think?

Comment: Ohh now I see what you mean... but that makes no sense to me physically! Btw, I have an answer to your question, I'm typing it. It'll take a while I think.

Comment: @PseudoApocaleone1 did you also notice the $\sin^2\theta$ in the denominator? That'll make the rest of the expression $\infty$, while $\sin2\theta$ makes it $0$. Interesting...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @dantopa Thanx! Just the thing I didn't know that I needed!

Comment: @ExtremeRaider, sorry I didn't notice your earlier comment about $sin^2x$, I don't think $sin^2x$ makes it zero because there is also 2g in the denominator outside, which would prevent the denominator from becoming zero..unless I am wrong?

Comment: That would mean that if there is no gravity, the range would be infinity..which makes sense I guess.

Comment: ```I don't think sin2x makes it zero because there is also 2g in the denominator outside,``` in response to this @PseudoApocaleone1, what I meant was that putting $\theta=0$ will make the denominator zero, and that makes the expression $\infty$. But there's also a $\sin 2x$ in the numerator, which makes  the expression zero... so the whole this is of the form $0 \times \infty$, which makes no sense to me. So sorry, I can't think about why we can't get the result for $\theta=0$ using this equation...

Comment: Yeah, I realized what you meant. But you see, there is $2g$ in the denominator outside, which multiplies with $1$ in the bracket inside, that makes the denominator non zero, if $g$ has some value, even if $sin^2x$ is zero.

Comment: @ExtremeRaider, it just clicked, what you actually meant. Hehe...sorry. So anything divided by 0 becomes infinity..yeah..that is a problem.

Comment: @PseudoApocaleone1 okay nvm, I was being stupid. We can use $\theta=0$ here, but first you'd have to distribute the $\sin 2\theta$ term inside, and take it inside the radical. It'll eventually cancel with the $\sin^2\theta$ in the denominator.

Comment: @ExtremeRaider, hmm..so we should only implement the value of zero after redistributing and simplifying the equation huh. Hmm..interesting. because if we directly implement the value in the equation..it would come out infinity or something..I am sorry, but this is a bit hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: I guess, I am missing some basic mathematical law here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little messing around, I figured it out. Here it goes:

Given equation:
$$d = \frac{v^2}{2g} \left( 1+ \sqrt{  1+ \frac{2g y_0}{v^2 \sin^2{\theta}}  } \right)\sin{2\theta}$$

$$\implies \dfrac{2gd}{v^2}=(\sin 2\theta) +\left[\dfrac{(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\sqrt{v^2\sin^2\theta+2gy_0}}{v\sin\theta}\right]$$
$$\implies \dfrac{2gd}{v^2}=2\cos\theta\left( \sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\frac{2gy_0}{v^2}} \right)$$
$$\implies \dfrac{gd}{v^2}\sec\theta-\sin\theta=\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\frac{2gy_0}{v^2}}$$

Let $\dfrac{gd}{v^2}=a$ and $\dfrac{2gy_0}{v^2}=b.$

$$\implies a\sec\theta-\sin\theta=\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+b}$$

Squaring on both sides,
$$\implies a^2\sec^2\theta+\sin^2\theta-2a\sec\theta\sin\theta=\sin^2
\theta+b$$
$$\implies a^2(1+\tan^2\theta)-2a\tan\theta-b=0$$
$$\implies a^2\tan^2\theta-2a\tan\theta+(a^2-b)=0$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Just implement the quadratic on this right? I will do that and try implementing the code. Let's see if this works. Many thanks!!

Comment: Yep just the quadratic. Go ahead and accept my answer if it's good enough for you, otherwise wait until someone else provides a different solution. Glad to help!

Comment: I think you lost a $v$ between the second and third line of your equations. $b$ should be $b = 2gy_0/v^2$.

Comment: @pH74 oh yes, that's what I wrote in my book but messed up the code. Thanks for pointing it out!